# Firebase push notifications device id is valid only once

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I have firebase push notifications set up in my android app. The first time I launch an app, I print out the device id in my FirebaseInstanceIdService. When I try to send a notification to this device id from the firebase console, it says that it was sent successfully, but I don't receive it in my FirebaseMessagingService. If I try to send once more, I get the following error:

[image: unregistered registration token]
This is how I initialize services inside manifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("TEST", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
}
}
```

FirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("TEST", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    sendNotification("sfa");
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewsFeedActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

This is how I initialize FirebaseApp inside my main activity onCreate method:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Comment: I guess its something to do with google's policy for avoiding spams. I read it somewhere in the docs.

Comment: Mate, could you provide the whole android manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Token will be refreshed on certain conditions:

- App deletes Instance ID
- App is restored on a new device
- User uninstalls/reinstall the app
- User clears app data

You have to make sure that you are using the same token that stored in your app to send the notifications to the app. If you accidentally reinstall or clear your app data, you might want to retrieve the new token before sending the notification.

Comment: After sending the first message, the device id doesn't change. I know, because I print it out in my onCreate.

Comment: Hmm,  I don't know how to help you anymore, it works for me. And it's not device id, it's token id. Device id and token id are two different things..